# How can I achieve a safe zone (PVP free) in ARK?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I am the administrator of a non-official PVP server. I've installed the **[Capitalism mods](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=747539326)** and our intention is to create a market zone in a specific position of the world map. Using the Capitalism mods a player can buy and sell resources from default market places, and a player can put him own market place to sell him items and dinos.

For all this, that zone must be a safe zone (PVP free) to avoid unwanted players from raiding the market structures and dinosaurs.

I'll ask for suggestions from experienced administrators about which would be the proper way to achieve this feature, maybe setting a specific value in the server config .ini files, or maybe using a 3rd party mod to prevent PVP in that zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen a perfect solution for this yet, but you could cluster your main server with one of the very small maps like the Event Arena and make the small map the Market.

I keep my eyes peeled for good solutions for this very question because having good people of both types around is fun and it *is* fascinating working out how to keep something like this alive and thriving.  You could experiment with PVE market events but I haven't experienced it yet, I've only played on PVE servers with PVP events.

Comment: Thanks for answer. If this is of your interest, I finally opted to use the mod "PVP Safe Zones 2" from the ARK workshop, it is discontinued by the author, but it seems to work fine by the moment, you could try it for your server. It is a indestructible item that creates an invisible orb and makes everything inside (players, criatures and structures) indestructible, and it has a configurable radious for the orb (you can enter a very big range value).

Comment: The thing that needs a little bit of meditation from the modders is this: lot of years of ARK development when it was launched in Steam in the 2013 as an early access game, with a huge modder community today for this game, and miles and miles of unofficial servers with the Capitalism mods installed, miles and miles of PVP servers with their own markets and zones inside the map that must be protected, but for whatever reason no body made in all these years a simple, stable and clean solution for the needs of almost every admin in this aspect of how we can protect a zone of "x"range in a server.